# Java sum a field (BigDecimal) of a list group by 2 fields

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of:

```
public class Dto {
    private Integer id;
    private String text;
    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

I tried:

```
 Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Dto>>> map =
            list.stream()
                .collect(
                     Collectors.groupingBy(
                     Dto::getText,
                     Collectors.groupingBy(Dto::getId)));
```

but this did not give a sum of the BigDecimal field

Also I would like to have the return structure like:

```
List<SumDto>

public class SumDto {
      private Integer id;
      private String text;
      private BigDecimal sum;
}
```

How could I achieve this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not summing anything, that's why you don't see the sum anywhere. You have to tell `Collectors.groupingBy` how to reduce elements downstream. Otherwise, it creates a `List` by default.

This is how you could do it:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, BigDecimal>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             Dto::getText, 
             Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Dto::getId, 
                        Collectors.reducing(
                                   BigDecimal.ZERO,
                                   Dto::getPrice, 
                                   BigDecimal::add))));
```

As to the return structure, I will leave that as an exercise ;)

Comment: I would have thought the final value of the nested map would have been a single instance of `SumDto` (clearly not a list of anything) even though it contains redundant information.